# How to iterate a single object into a new array of multiple objects within a defined format

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, javascript-objects

I have the following object that will have multiple properties

```
let features: {
  durable: 5,
  weight: 4
}
```

I need to cast it into a certain format the server accepts, like example below. The above `features` values are put in the `value` property and `features` property name ("durable" etc) into the `category.name`

```
"score": [
  {
    "value": 5,
    "category": {
      "name": "durable"
    }
  },
  {
    "value": 4,
    "category": {
      "name": "weight"
    }
  }
]
```

In the POST service i feed the data into a property and it gets sent to server (simplified example). The new array of objects should be declared in `ratings` property below

```
const scoreData= {
  title: something,
  ratings: score
};

return this.http.post(this.API_URL, scoreData);
```

**EDIT**: Selected solution does work! But might be over complicated? For comparison, what would be a way to iterate the `features` object's key and value properties *into* the new array, example:

```
const scoreData = {
            title: "something",
            ratings: [
                {
                    "value": features.value, // Iterating through values here
                    "category": {
                        "name": features.key // ... and here
                    }
                }
            ]
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to convert that particular object to above specified format ? If so, you can do it like this :

```js
var k={features: { durable: 5, weight: 4}};

var score = Object.entries(Object.values(k)[0]).map(([k,v])=> ({ value : v, category: { name : k } }));

console.log(score);
```